# Can a lost Minecraft: PE world be retrieved?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has spent ages building his Minecraft: Pocket Edition world on my iPad. However, the iPad was stolen.

Is there any other way he can access his world from another iPad or laptop, etc?

Comment: did you backup your ipad?

Comment: This looks more like a [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) question. Answers will be barely related to videogames.

Comment: @SysDragon look at the upvotes how many people agree that this is a good question for this site

Answer (score 13):

**Restore on new iPad**

If you are going to buy a new iPad, and backed up the stolen one you can easily restore the old backup and you will have the world back again. but you have to install all the apps (including minecraft again)

> [What does iTunes backup](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4946)
>
> - ...
> - App Store app data (except the app itself, its tmp, and Caches folder)
> - App settings, preferences, and data, including documents
> - ...

I recommend this anyways because it will be identical to you old iPad.

Save the old backup to a external storage, because it might happen that itunes overwrites the backup and everything is lost.

**Restore on PC**

- [This forumlink might help you](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/1966323-move-pocket-edition-world-to-pc)
- [and this youtube-video (i did not watch it)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gmf6Mfa7HFQ)

Comment: You didn't even watch the video you're linking to?  How is that better than what OP could have done himself?

Comment: @ChaseSandmann i don't understand your argumentation.